# grep --include acts like --exclude

Tags: grep

I'm trying to make use of the --include option of grep, but it doesn't behave as I expect.

Consider this simplified test:

**Setup**

```
me@de31:~/tmp$ cat file.h
This is a .h file
me@de31:~/tmp$ cat file.c
This is a .c file
```

**Verify**

```
me@de31:~/tmp$ grep "This is a" *
file.c:This is a .c file
file.h:This is a .h file
```

**Use --include**

```
me@de31:~/tmp$ grep "This is a" * --include="*.c"
file.h:This is a .h file

me@de31:~/tmp$ grep "This is a" * --include="*.h"
file.c:This is a .c file
```

**Use --exclude**

```
me@de31:~/tmp$ grep "This is a" * --exclude="*.c"
file.h:This is a .h file

me@de31:~/tmp$ grep "This is a" * --exclude="*.h"
file.c:This is a .c file
```

As you can see, --include has the same output as --exclude.  Another post on stackexchange claims "-r" is required, but I tried that as well, and it did not change the output.

Comment: When using `-r`, change the bare `*` (a list of files) to `.` (a directory name).  It would also be good to link to the other post. :)

Answer (score 2):

This would appear to be a bug of some sort. Found this bug filing on Ubuntu launchpad, titled: [--include does the same as --exclude!](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grep/+bug/651867).

Your examples on my Fedora 14 system:

```
$ more file.*
::::::::::::::
file.c
::::::::::::::
This is a .c file

::::::::::::::
file.h
::::::::::::::
This is a .h file
```

#### include

```
$ grep "This is a" * --include="*.c"
file.c:This is a .c file
$ grep "This is a" * --include="*.h"
file.h:This is a .h file
```

#### exclude

```
$ grep "This is a" * --exclude="*.c"
file.h:This is a .h file
$ grep "This is a" * --exclude="*.h"
file.c:This is a .c file
```

#### grep version

```
$ grep --version
grep (GNU grep) 2.8
```

Comment: Thanks for the link.  Somehow I didn't find it while googling.

$ grep --version
grep (GNU grep) 2.10

Sounds like it's been fixed and re-broken a few times.

Comment: @user2100564 - yup. Not sure what the issue is. If you get a sec. can you please mark this as the accepted answer so that others know this question has been solved? Thanks.